# При установке пакета NuGet не копируются статические файлы

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, .net-5

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - имеется  проект (библиотека классов) с рядом статических файлов (Папка files и в ней ряд папок(содержащих  также txt файлы) и txt файлы).

Мне необходимо упаковать данные файлы в пакет NuGet для платформы .Net 5. Перепробовал различные варианты добавления статических файлов - результат нулевой, при установке пакета в тестовый проект не происходит копирование статических файлов, при этом пакет считается установленным.

Прогуглив эту тему выяснил, что для net Core функционал копирования статических файлов более не поддерживается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, получилось ли у кого обойти данное ограничение? Если да то каким образом удалось осуществить копирование статических файлов через пакет NuGet на платформе .Net Core (.Net 5)?